# Select distinct column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I am making a query using mutiple tables and i want to get a distinct product name("`designacao`") however I've already tried adding `DISTINCT` and `RIGHT JOINs` but it didn't work.

Please check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25584/1/0) with the Query and the data

I want the same query as the provided but with DISTINCT "designacao"

Comment: JS FIDDLE ? Use SQL Fiddle instead.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Where is the query you tried? Please post it here.

Comment: What didn't work ? Provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Replaced JSFiddle with SQLFiddle, please check it

Comment: @DaftDev - Which value to select from the columns `SUPERFICIE  LOCALIZACAO  PRECO` for each distinct `designacao`?

Comment: @mahmoud gamal all of them. i just don't want repeated "DESIGNACAO"

Comment: There are multiple values for each `DESIGNACAO` how do  you want to display all of them? Do you want to display them concatenated as comma separated or what? Please post the expected result set.

Comment: @DaftDev - Impossible. You want distinct `DESIGNACAO` but also want to keep other fields?

Comment: You can't do that as you have different values in localizacao and preco for the same designacao. You'll have to aggredate one way or another.

Comment: @hims056 No, i'm sorry if i didn't express myself the best way... i want something like `distinct designacao where min(preco)` (preco means price)

Comment: @DaftDev - But what about other field (SUPERFICIE and LOCALIZACAO)? Just show you expected output in the question.

Comment: @mahmoud gamal Sorry i didn't explain it very well from the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select produtos.designacao, produtos.marca,produtos.categoria, lojas.superficie, lojas.localizacao, produtos_lojas.preco 
from produtos_lojas 
inner join lojas on lojas.id = produtos_lojas.id_loja 
inner join produtos on produtos.id = produtos_lojas.id_produto 
where produtos_lojas.preco=
(
  select min(pl.preco) 
  from produtos_lojas pl
  inner join lojas l on l.id = pl.id_loja 
  inner join produtos p on p.id = pl.id_produto 
  where produtos.designacao = p.designacao
)
```

### SQL Fiddle [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25584/16/0)

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @DaftDev - I got what you wanted after Parado's answer.

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT keyword will get eliminate any duplicate row. Since your rows are different due to the other columns you are selecting, you will only be able to pick up each designacao once if you include only the designacao column in your query.